# How to Transfer Learning Pre-trained models from Tensorflow Model Zoo

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I need to transfer learning some detections of my own dataset into pre-trained models from Tensorflow Model Zoo for example Centernet_1024x1024.

I have searched a lot of tutorials but all of them do it using keras so it does not fit what I really need.

Would anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for a simple classification problem or an object detection problem? If its object detection here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection (Choose tensorflow 2)

Comment: it is for a object detection problem. I already open the link and i cant find any information about transfer learning :(

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md

Comment: but this is for fine-tune and i need transfer learning

Comment: https://github.com/armaanpriyadarshan/Training-a-Custom-TensorFlow-2.X-Object-Detector, here's a tutorial in more detail but fyi finetuning is transfer learning because both just train the last few layers on your custom dataset